# Return json value by key with all html tags and insert to dom

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, header

**AJAX**

```
var load = function (url) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    url: url,
    data: {'url': url},
    success: function(data) {
       $('#content').html(data.content);
    }
  });
};
```

**JSON**

```
$array = array(
  'id' => $data->id,
  'date' => date("F d, Y", strtotime($data->timer)),
  'author' => $data->creator,
  'time_to_read' => $data->timeread,
  'title' => $data->title,
  'content' => htmlspecialchars($data->content),
);

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($array);
```

**Explanation:**

Everything is fine, i can return whatever i want. However, my content key in array has a lot of html tags, classes, id's and other stuff. On return `data.content`, it returns value with quotes as first and last character. Looks like, it returns as simple text/string.

**Question:**

How, can i return proper value of `data.content` and insert to `#content` with all working html tags?

Sorry for bad english and thanks for any answers.

Comment: just trim that double quotes like this data.content.substring(1, data.content.length-1);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
    var load = function (url) {
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: url,
        data: {'url': url},
        success: function(data) {
           var string = ($.parseHTML(data['content'])[0]).data;
           $('#content').html(string);
        }
      });
    };
```

Comment: ``Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token & in JSON at position 0 at Function.parse [as parseJSON] (<anonymous>)``

Comment: looks like its okay now.

Comment: I have updated again, I am 100% sure that this one will solve your problem.

Comment: Good job. Thanks